# MapBox for Android inside a Service

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to instantiate a **MapBox map** inside an *Android Service* because I need to stream a navigation routing with my app in background.

Right now I created a *Service* that when started run an *Hander* on the *main looper*, and from there, if my map isn't instantiated yet, I inflate a layout (before I tried to create it by hand, but nothing changed), find the *MapView*, and fire the **getMapASync** in order to obtain the **MapboxMap** object.

It all works, but getMapAsync callback never gets called

Here is a sample code I used

```
public class MapBoxHandlerService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "MapBoxHandlerService";
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    static MapBoxHandlerService instance;

    MapView mapView;
    MapboxMap map;

    private final static class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) { super(looper); }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            currentStartId = msg.arg1;

            final Intent intent = (Intent) msg.obj;
            if (intent==null)
                return;

            if (instance.mapView==null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(instance.getApplicationContext());
                View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapbox_layout, null);

                instance.mapView = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                instance.mapView.onCreate(null);
                instance.mapView.addOnDidFailLoadingMapListener((String errorMessage)->{
                    Logger.e(instance.getApplicationContext(),TAG,errorMessage);
                });
                instance.mapView.addOnDidFinishLoadingMapListener(()->{
                    Logger.i(instance.getApplicationContext(),TAG,"map loaded");
                });
                instance.mapView.addOnWillStartLoadingMapListener(()->{
                    Logger.i(instance.getApplicationContext(),TAG,"start map loading");
                });
                instance.mapView.addOnWillStartRenderingMapListener(()->{
                    Logger.i(instance.getApplicationContext(),TAG,"start map rendering");
                });
                instance.mapView.getMapAsync((@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) -> {
                    instance.map = mapboxMap;

                    instance.map.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, (Style loadedMapStyle) -> {
                        LocationComponent locationComponent = instance.map.getLocationComponent();
                        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING_GPS);
                        locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.GPS);
                    });
                });
                instance.mapView.onStart();
                instance.mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        instance=this;

        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj=intent;
        msg.arg1=startId;
        msg.arg2=0;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        startForeground(9, Utils.createServiceNotification(this, "MapBox service",getResources().getString(R.string.service_active)));

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
}
```

and when this service is started, I already called
`Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), MapBoxAccessToken)`
outside the service (in the App onCreate)

Any idea on what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Try to use workmanager. Workmanager will help to perform any task or process in background even app is kill

Comment: @GovindPrajapati thanks, what should change by using Workmanager?

Comment: workmanager has doWork() method in it. As per your task you need to put your functionality in doWork() method as schedule it like periodic for continously working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out myself what was the problem: I forgot to add my layout to the *WindowManager* service and I needed to set the *MapView* **TextureMode** attribute.